# fastest way to combine two huge list of tuples in python

Tags: python, performance, list

I have two list like these:

```
L1 = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'm'), (3, 'd') ....] 
L2 = [('b', 1), ('f', 2), ('x', 1), ('w', 3), ('j', 2) ... ]
```

and I want to produce:

```
L3 = [('a','b'),('m','f'),('a','x'),('d','w'),('m','j'), ...]
```

I mean, where second element in tuple of list L1 match with first element in tuple of list L2.

L1 and L2 are above 12 millions of tuples.

I have a code that works using nested loops for comparison between 'keys' of each tuples but is fairly inefficient.

What could be a good alternative to do it in the faster way ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are L1 and L2 the same length?  Is L1 sorted already?

Comment: @wim, L1 is about 12 millions and L2 is over 19 millions. None of both lists are sorted, in fact I was wondering if sorting could be help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dictionaries have O(1) select/insert complexity. Use them:

```
L1_dict = dict(L1)
L3 = [(L1_dict[k], v) for v, k in L2 if k in L1_dict]
```